# Can someone correct me about Windows 2008 DFS implementation

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster, dfs-r

I have 2 two Windows 2003 file servers using DoubleTake at the moment. They are in an 2003 AD domain. And each server has it's own disk set. It is time to replace the servers...

I want to use Windows 2008 64bit Ent. I was thinking of using DFS-R to replace DoubleTake. The part I'm not sure about is clustering. Do I need to have shared storage if each server has a copy of the data? I want to have the data available to the same share name, so maybe I don't fully understand how DFS is set up.

I currently have about 6TB of data. I expect to grow by 3TB a year on these file servers.

Any resources/books that could teach me would be good to know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late but if you were still waiting for an answer, I think you should see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/06/29/deploying-dfsr-clustering-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Please note you will need Windows Server 2008 R2 for the clustered DFSR instance. And yes you will need shared storage accessible by all nodes of the cluster.

You should also do the schema extensions for Windows Server 2008 R2 as per http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/07/02/what-are-the-schema-extension-requirements-for-running-windows-server-2008-dfsr.aspx . But the AD itself can remain on Windows 2003 DCs until you are ready to upgrade that.